# Drop the duplicated index and keep one in the multi-index dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My toy data `df` has three layers of index: `name`, `name`, `year`, assuming the index columns `name` and `name` both names and contents are duplicated, so I need to keep one only.

```
import pandas as pd

# create MultiIndex
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('name1', 'name1', '2020'),
    ('name1', 'name1', '2021'),
    ('name2', 'name2', '2020'),
    ('name2', 'name2', '2021'),
    ('name3', 'name3', '2020'),
    ('name3', 'name3', '2021')
], names=['name', 'name', 'year'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'quantity': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35],
    'price': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350]
}, index=index)

print(df)
```

Out:

```
                  quantity  price
name  name  year                 
name1 name1 2020        10    100
            2021        15    150
name2 name2 2020        20    200
            2021        25    250
name3 name3 2020        30    300
            2021        35    350
```

I tried the following code and did not succeed:

```
# Create a Boolean sequence, where TRUE indicates that the index is repeated
duplicates = df.index.duplicated(keep='first')

# Use Bolnes to choose those lines that are not repeated
df = df[~duplicates]
df
```

Out:

```
                  quantity  price
name  name  year                 
name1 name1 2020        10    100
            2021        15    150
name2 name2 2020        20    200
            2021        25    250
name3 name3 2020        30    300
            2021        35    350
```

If we `reset_index()` then drop duplicated columns, we will get `ValueError: cannot insert name, already exists`.

How to get the following results? Thanks.

```
            quantity  price
name  year                 
name1 2020        10    100
      2021        15    150
name2 2020        20    200
      2021        25    250
name3 2020        30    300
      2021        35    350
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
df.droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
            quantity  price
name  year
name1 2020        10    100
      2021        15    150
name2 2020        20    200
      2021        25    250
name3 2020        30    300
      2021        35    350
```

If you don't know the ordering of names in the index, you could find the first occurrence of `name` in the index:

```
level = df.index.names.index('name')
df.droplevel(level)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

I think a simple way to do this is to convert the index to a DataFrame, use the drop_duplicates() method, and then convert it back to an index.

```
frame = df.index.to_frame(allow_duplicates=True).T.drop_duplicates().T
out = df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(frame))
```

out:

```
            quantity  price
name  year                 
name1 2020        10    100
      2021        15    150
name2 2020        20    200
      2021        25    250
name3 2020        30    300
      2021        35    350
```

There might be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```
# Rename index layer
df.index.set_names(['name1', 'name', 'year'], inplace=True)

# Delete the index level named 'name1'
df.reset_index('name1', drop=True, inplace=True)
df
```

Out:

```
            quantity  price
name  year                 
name1 2020        10    100
      2021        15    150
name2 2020        20    200
      2021        25    250
name3 2020        30    300
      2021        35    350
```

Answer (score 1):

### Rename indices to remove duplicates + reset_index + drop

I think you can do this way also:

```py
import pandas as pd

# create MultiIndex
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('name1', 'name1', '2020'),
    ('name1', 'name1', '2021'),
    ('name2', 'name2', '2020'),
    ('name2', 'name2', '2021'),
    ('name3', 'name3', '2020'),
    ('name3', 'name3', '2021')
], names=['name', 'name', 'year'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'quantity': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35],
    'price': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350]
}, index=index)


df = df.rename_axis(index=["to_be_removed", "name", "year"]) #...(1)
df = df.reset_index(level="to_be_removed") #...(2)
df = df.drop(columns=["to_be_removed"]) #...(3)
print(df)

>>>
            quantity  price
name  year
name1 2020        10    100
      2021        15    150
name2 2020        20    200
      2021        25    250
name3 2020        30    300
      2021        35    350
```

It works as follows:
(1) Rename indices to remove duplication.
(2) Use `reset_index` to turn one of the 'name' index column (which is now renamed) into data column.
(3) Drop the data column to remove.

### Why `df.index.duplicated` did not work

It seems that the reason why your first approach didn't work is because the `df.index.duplicated()` is not checking whether there are duplicate index **names** but it does check if there are duplicate tuple of (name, name, year) within the dataframe records:

```py
import pandas as pd

# create MultiIndex
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('name1', 'name1', '2020'),
    ('name1', 'name1', '2021'),
    ('name2', 'name2', '2020'),
    ('name2', 'name2', '2021'),
    ('name3', 'name3', '2020'),
    ('name3', 'name3', '2021')
], names=['name', 'name', 'year'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'quantity': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35],
    'price': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350]
}, index=index)

print(df.index.duplicated(keep='first'))

>>> [False False False False False False]
# All 6 tuples from your toy MultiIndex are different
# so this gives all false values.
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic solution use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with drop duplicated index names:

```
s = pd.Series(df.index.names).duplicated()

df = df.reset_index(list(s.index[s]), drop=True)
print (df)
            quantity  price
name  year                 
name1 2020        10    100
      2021        15    150
name2 2020        20    200
      2021        25    250
name3 2020        30    300
      2021        35    350
```

Another sample:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('name1', 'name1', 'name1'),
    ('name1', 'name1', 'name1'),
    ('name2', 'name2', 'name1'),
    ('name2', 'name2', 'name1'),
    ('name3', 'name3', 'name1'),
    ('name3', 'name3', 'name1')
], names=['name', 'name', 'name'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'quantity': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35],
    'price': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350]
}, index=index)

print(df)
                   quantity  price
name  name  name                  
name1 name1 name1        10    100
            name1        15    150
name2 name2 name1        20    200
            name1        25    250
name3 name3 name1        30    300
            name1        35    350
```

---

```
s = pd.Series(df.index.names).duplicated()

df = df.reset_index(list(s.index[s]), drop=True)
print (df)
       quantity  price
name                  
name1        10    100
name1        15    150
name2        20    200
name2        25    250
name3        30    300
name3        35    350
```